# How to add local image of project folder in canvas?

Tags: reactjs, image, canvas, konvajs

I am trying to open a project folder image in the canvas without uploading it in a file input. But it is not showing there and I am using `react-konva` to add the image.

Here is the code where I am trying to upload the image:

```
      const img = new window.Image();
      img.src = require('../../../assets/images/71.png');
      img.onload = function () {
        const img_width = this.width;
        console.log('the image', require('../../../assets/images/71.png'));
        const img_height = this.height;

        const max = img_width > img_height ? 100 : 100;
        const ratio = (img_width > img_height ? (img_width / max) : (img_height / max))
        setOriginalDim({ width: img_width, height: img_height });
        setDimensions({ width: img_width/ratio, height: img_height/ratio });
        const theImg = new Konva.Image({
          image: this,
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: img_width/ratio,
          height: img_height/ratio,
          name: 'background_image',
          draggable: true
        });

        if (layerRef.current != null) {
          console.log('image', theImg);
          layerRef.current.add(theImg);
          layerRef.current.draw();
        }
      };
```

And my react component is this:

```
<Stage
              width={dimensions.width}
              height={dimensions.height}
              onMouseDown={handleStageMouseDown}
              style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', boxShadow: '0 0 6px 0 #666' }}
              ref={stageRef}
              id="certificate_canvas"
            >
              <Layer
                ref={layerRef}
              />
</Stage>
```

The `onload` part is not executing also the image is not loading into the canvas. How do I add the project folder image without uploading it

Comment: What did you have in `console.log('the image', require('../../../assets/images/71.png'));` does it logs image URL?

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
img.src = require('../../../assets/images/71.png');
```

use

```
img.src = '../../../assets/images/71.png';
```

you dont need the require function

Comment: Even after that the it's not calling the onload callback

Comment: can you post a photo of your console??

Comment: the log statement is not working, the code does not reach there

Comment: its not showing any errors?
try logging the src of the image after setting it
also i would recommend that you use 
const img = document.createElement("image");
isntead of 
const img = new window.Image();

Comment: the src is being printed, but img is not showing, both ways did not work with external image URL the image is coming but for local image it is not

Comment: as you mentioned you are using react..are you sure you are putting the assets in the correct folder(the public folder)
or your path might not be correct